# ASP.Net Form authentication 401.2 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have an issue that's driving me nuts. I have created a ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2015 with a predefined template. The target framework is 4.5

When I added Forms authentication, all I got was a 401.2 message.

This is how I configured the application:
I created a Login.aspx page. Then in the web.config I added the following properties in the system.web section:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="30"
             name=".ASPXAUTH"
             path="/"
             defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

I checked some other posts, but none helped me out so far:

This one is not applicable:
[Access is Denied - 401.2: Unauthorized Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802673/access-is-denied-401-2-unauthorized-error)

This one looked promising, but no cigar for my app:
[.NET Forms Authentication using IIS8.0 Express (vs2013) - 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903140/net-forms-authentication-using-iis8-0-express-vs2013-401-2-unauthorized)

This one got me thinking:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35925125/980201

When I check the IIS(Express) logfile, this is what I get:

```
2017-02-24 19:29:22 ::1 GET / .... - 302
2017-02-24 19:29:22 ::1 GET /Login ReturnUrl=%2f .... - 401
```

Where did the .aspx in Login.aspx go?

So I removed all FriendlyURL stuff, but no luck again. In a final attempt I changed my config to:

```
<forms loginUrl="LoginXXX.aspx"
```

And this is what I got:

```
2017-02-24 19:45:37 ::1 GET / ... - 302
2017-02-24 19:45:37 ::1 GET /LoginXXX.aspx ReturnUrl=%2f 57745 - 404
```

Why does .Net redirect to login instead of login.aspx ?
Any other thoughts on my app and config file?

Thanks a lot!

Regards Roeland

**Edit**
Some unexpected turn of events: when I start debugging in VS with Login.aspx.cs as the current tab, it fails. When I start debugging from Default.aspx.cs it works. Setting the **Start Action** of my project to Default.aspx solves the issue. However, when the site runs, changing the url to login.aspx makes it fail again.

Why? It doesn't make sense to me that only page that is everyone allowed to see, cannot be navigated directly.

Comment: Did you check if anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS?

Comment: Hi Ghini, yes. It is allowed in the applicationhost.config.

Comment: This answer fixed it for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797308/538763

Answer (score -1):

If you used Visual Studio to create a default project, which you then used to enable forms authentication, then the problem is that Forms Authentication is disabled by default, because Identity Framework is the default authentication mechanism in VS 2015.

Look for the this entry in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

And remove the "remove".

Comment: Hi Erik,this entry is not in my web.config